# Swift location program wont update

Tags: xcode, swift, location

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this program?

I'm using swift and I'm trying to create an app which will give me values such as longitude/latitude etc. When I run the program, the build has 'succeeded' however, nothing prints to the logs or changes in the simulator.

However, the these are the errors that pop up.

```
    Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

and

```
     Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

[[image: pic]
Can someone please tell me what I need to do. I already added the CoreLocation framework too and imported it into my program.

I recently updated to Version 7.1 beta.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a simple example that works for me, from a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801961/swift-2-cant-get-user-location-with-cllocationmanager/35973586#35973586

Answer (score 0):

First, try to clean the project: Product > Clean, or empty the DerivedData folder.

Then if it's not fixed, this error happened to me when I use functions with ambiguous declaration (for example, using .Case instead of MyEnum.Case).

Edit your message by adding your code if the issue still occurs.